# the same Neo4j Cypher becomes slower while loop

Tags: c#, neo4j

I'm working with Neo4jClient and c#. Now i have some code like this:

```
client.Cypher
                    .Merge("(u:User { UniqueIdInItsApp: {id} , AppId: {appId} })")
                    .ForEach("(f in {friends} | MERGE (u)-[:" + FriendRelation + "]->(:User {UniqueIdInItsApp: f,AppId:{appId}}))")
                    .WithParams(new
                    {
                        id = friendsFromId,
                        appId = _appId,
                        friends = friendsToId
                    }).ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I have a loop to call the code above. but it seems to become slower. when first run in loop, it may cost 0.5 second, but last run in loop may cost 5 seconds. I can't figure out why it happens. Can anyone help?

Comment: What timing mechanism are you using that's telling you it's running slower?   What does the loop that calls this code look like?   What is in {friends}?

Comment: is it maybe because when first run, you have actually no relationships in the database and thus the match query is fast, but later on you have plenty of relationships in the db created, and thus the match query is slow? could you please run the same script 2x, if the second run will be slow since the beginning, this would definitely be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index defined on the :User label? I believe you're hitting a performance issue that was overlooked in the 2.0 release. This should have been resolved in the new milestone, 2.1.0-M02, could you try that and see if the issue persists?